# How to write a form including CheckBox, radio buttons and selected option value in ROR.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me to convert my total HTML form into ROR format form and give some idea about retrive all selected values into controller page.

My HTML form:

```
<%= form_for @student,:url => {:action => "stdrecord"} do |f| %>
<tr>
<td>DATE OF BIRTH</td>

<td>
<select name="Birthday_day" id="Birthday_Day">
<option value="-1">Day:</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>

<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>

<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>

<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>

<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select id="Birthday_Month" name="Birthday_Month">
<option value="-1">Month:</option>
<option value="January">Jan</option>
<option value="February">Feb</option>
<option value="March">Mar</option>
<option value="April">Apr</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">Jun</option>
<option value="July">Jul</option>
<option value="August">Aug</option>
<option value="September">Sep</option>
<option value="October">Oct</option>
<option value="November">Nov</option>
<option value="December">Dec</option>
</select>

<select name="Birthday_Year" id="Birthday_Year">

<option value="-1">Year:</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>

<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>

<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>GENDER</td>
<td>
Male <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" />
Female <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>HOBBIES <br /><br /><br /></td>

<td>
Drawing
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Drawing" value="Drawing" />
Singing
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Singing" value="Singing" />
Dancing
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Dancing" value="Dancing" />
Sketching
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Cooking" value="Cooking" />
<br />
Others
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby_Other" value="Other">
<input type="text" name="Other_Hobby" maxlength="30" />
</td>
</tr>
<%= f.submit "submit" %>

<% end %>
```

Please help me to acess all desired value while selected inside the controller page inside the create method.I am using rails-4 and ruby 1.9.3.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read through [form_helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), and go through some tutorials.

Comment: There is no shortcut...Read rails guide... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a great tutorial on ruby-on-rails guides, even making a project from scratch. You can see the first reference in your comments I'll duplicate it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html, 2 check get started with rails, it has many good things and it's all described http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
<input type="text" name="student[Other_Hobby]" maxlength="30" />

<input type="checkbox" name="student[Hobby_Drawing]" value="Drawing" />

<select name="student[Birthday_day]" id="Birthday_Day">
<option value="-1">Day:</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How is this related to the question? And there's **nothing** about this is related to Ruby or Rails.